# SQL Server - Limit maximum of 8 records per week to be inserted for a staff_schedule table for a single staff

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a staff table and then staff_schedule table which references staff id. I want to limit the number of schedules created for a single staff to 8 records per week. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

What I have so far..

```
CREATE TABLE Staff
(
staffID int,
fullName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
s_category varchar(25),
s_email varchar(50),
s_contactNo int,
speciality varchar(100),
qualifications varchar(250),
pre_employment varchar(200),
salary numeric(8,2),
staff_gender char(1),
CONSTRAINT PK_Staff PRIMARY KEY (staffID),
CONSTRAINT CHK_StaffGender CHECK (staff_gender='M' OR staff_gender='F'),
CONSTRAINT CHK_FullName CHECK (fullName NOT LIKE '%0%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%1%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%2%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%3%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%4%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%5%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%6%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%7%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%8%' AND fullName NOT LIKE '%9%'),
CONSTRAINT CHK_SALARY CHECK (salary>0 AND salary<=150000)
);

CREATE TABLE Staff_Allocation
(
allocationId int,
staff_Id int,
branch_Id int,
staff_start_date DateTime,
staff_end_date DateTime,
CONSTRAINT PK_Staff_Allocation PRIMARY KEY (allocationId),
CONSTRAINT FK_Staff_Allocation_Staff FOREIGN KEY (staff_Id) REFERENCES Staff(staffID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Staff_Allocation_Branch FOREIGN KEY (branch_Id) REFERENCES Branch(branchID),
CONSTRAINT CHK_StaffAllocationRotaDaily CHECK (DATEDIFF(hh, staff_start_date, staff_end_date) <=6)
);
```

Comment: 8 per week, as in the title, or 8 in total? BTW, it's _rows_, not records.

Comment: Make it easy to help you - simplify your question. For example remove all columns and other stuff not needed to explain the problem. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 8 rows per week for a staff

Comment: How would you like to determine a week? Within 7 days or Monday to Sunday etc?

Comment: Within 7 days is fine

Comment: If it would be for 7 rows per week, then probably putting a unique combined index on (staff_Id,  staff_start_date) would solve it, I guess.  But since it's 8 per week, it'll probably need a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger is definitely the way to go for enforcing this constraint. TABLE constraints cannot enforce requirements that span multiple rows.

There are a number of things to test for your requirements

1. Single row inserted
2. Multiple rows attempted to be inserted across different staff_ids
3. Multiple rows attempted to be inserted for same staff_id

Below trigger will satisfy these. I left the date range check as empty as I'm not sure the exact criteria. The inner query collects all the rows from rows being inserted along with all rows already present for staff_ids in the current insert. The outer query aggregates by staff_id after applying the date range criteria. Finally the IF EXISTS check is used to throw an error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_checkScheduleCount
ON Staff_Allocation AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM 
    ( 
      SELECT staff_id, staff_start_date, staff_end_date
      FROM
           inserted // relevant columns from the current set of rows 
                    // attempting to be inserted 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT staff_id, staff_start_date, staff_end_date
      FROM 
           Staff_Allocation
      WHERE
          staff_id IN (SELECT staff_id FROM inserted)
          // rows already in the table for staff being touched in this insert
    ) AS staffRows
    WHERE
       <apply you criteria on staff_start_date and staff_end_date>
    GROUP BY             
       staff_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 8
) 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'More than 8 rows', 16, -1)
END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instead of trigger:
Sample Query for your reference:

```
CREATE TRIGGER INSTEADOF_INS
ON Staff_Allocation
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @CNT_ALLOC TINYINT
DECLARE @CNT_ALLOC_TAB TINYINT
DECLARE @ST_DATE DATE
DECLARE @END_DATE DATE

SELECT @ST_DATE=DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())-1), GETDATE()) 
SELECT @END_DATE=DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())), GETDATE()) 

SELECT @CNT_ALLOC=COUNT(*) 
FROM Staff_Allocation S INNER JOIN INSERTED I
ON S.staff_Id = I.staff_Id AND S.staff_start_date>@ST_DATE AND S.staff_end_date<@END_DATE

IF (@CNT_ALLOC >8 )
BEGIN
RAISERROR (N'8 rows Per Week',
16, 1)
RETURN
END
INSERT INTO Staff_Allocation (allocationId, staff_Id, branch_Id,staff_start_date,staff_end_date) 
SELECT allocationId, staff_Id, branch_Id,staff_start_date,staff_end_date 
FROM inserted 
END
GO
```

Comment: Is this a single trigger?

Comment: This trigger has a bug if the insert is for multiple rows with different staff_ids. It will end up counting the allocation rows across different staff_ids. The fix is to count with group by staff_id and check for any of the aggregates to be > 8

Comment: Also has issues when the insert has multiple rows with same staff_id (double counting) and doesn't consider new rows being added for a staff_id towards the limit. Counts only the rows already in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a trigger you could just use an IF statement

```
  DECLARE @TableCount INT

    SELECT @TableCount = COUNT(*)

    FROM YourTable

    WHERE StartDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()
          AND EndDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()

    IF @TableCount < 8

    INSERT...

    ELSE 

    RAISERROR...

    RETURN
```

Comment: Is this for all staff or 1 staff id?